# Mercurial: apply patch to working directory

Tags: mercurial, patch, tortoisehg, working-directory

I have a *.patch file with some changes and I need to apply it to working directory without commit. So, is it possible with TortoiseHg? Or, if not, is there any option to rollback commit into working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution.

```
Repository / Import / Preview (Combo Box)
```

Here you can choose Working Directory option.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the [Shelve Tool](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/shelve.html), where you can freely move chunks, and entire files between different patches and the working directory.

The button is just above the commit message box:

[image: Shelve Tool]

And it gives you a nice interface to freely move bits and pieces around.

[image: Shelve Interface]